# Integration of S3 storage with Jackrabbit Oak implementation application deployed on GCP

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak, spring-cloud-gcp

I am working on Spring boot application(Content Management System) which will store multiple files in amazon-s3 repository with the help of jack rabbit oak node structure implementation and all node metadata will get store in PostgreSQL 10.4 db.

I will be deploy my application on **GCP** platform, before that I want to know how I can integrate S3 storage with my application, is there any google cloud API/service available?

Comment: You will deploy your application in Google Cloud Platform what? are you planing on use Compute Engine, GKE, App Engine? the answer may be different depending on the product

Comment: @Chris32 Compute Engine

Comment: @Chris32 We have instances on GCP, and there we have Cloud Foundry, So I will be deploying my application on Cloud Foundry. So is there any API service which I can use to communicate with AWS S3 for file upload/download.

Comment: what about just using the [Amazon S3 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html)? I've never used either Cloud Foundry or Amazon s3

Comment: @Chris32 I will try to use Amazon S3 API and will share my findings.